# VBA For Each ws only executes code on active sheet

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

I want to format a worksheet the same way in every sheet, currently the code works fine, except for the `for each ws in workbook` section.

All the code executes well enough, but only in the activesheet.
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance,

```
Option Explicit
Sub prepareForInput()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim answer As Variant
Dim i As Integer, lastcol As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Would you like to update the tracker sheet automatically?", vbYesNo)
If answer = vbYes Then
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Range("A1:A100").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 11
        'hide newly unneeded columns
        For i = 1 To 3
            Columns(lastcol).Hidden = True
            lastcol = lastcol + 1
        Next i
        lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'paste across columns
        For i = 1 To 3
            Columns(lastcol).Copy Columns(lastcol + 3)
            lastcol = lastcol - 1
        Next i
    Next ws
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        .Range("A1:A100").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 11
        'hide newly unneeded columns
        For i = 1 To 3
            .Columns(lastcol).Hidden = True
            lastcol = lastcol + 1
        Next i
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'paste across columns
        For i = 1 To 3
            .Columns(lastcol).Copy .Columns(lastcol + 3)
            lastcol = lastcol - 1
        Next i
    End With
Next Ws
```

Comment: Knew I'd be missing something simple like this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix things like Range("a1:a10") with ws, so ws.range("a1:a10") or select ws in each loop.  Without Range & Cells will act on the active sheet.